# Doctrine 2: Error: Class "..\.." has no field or association named "..."

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, dql

When searching I came up with many results of people having similar problems but they were always related to association errors. I'm trying add a simple text field to a table in a database and, for the life of me, I can't figure out what's different about this time - when I've done it with no problems many times before.

I've added a 'record_checksum' field to 4 different entities, but I will use just one, here to simplify the example. (The same error happens for all 4).

Here is an example of my Entity\Cloud.php file, with the '**record_checksum**' field added at the bottom:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

namespace Entity;

/**
 * Entity\Cloud
 *
 * @orm:Table(name="cloud")
 * @orm:Entity
 * @orm:HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Cloud
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @orm:Column(name="id", type="integer", length="13")
     * @orm:Id
     * @orm:GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var float $position_x
     *
     * @orm:Column(name="position_x", type="float", length=9)
     */
    private $position_x;

    /**
     * @var float $position_y
     *
     * @orm:Column(name="position_y", type="float", length=9)
     */
    private $position_y;

    /**
     * @var string $commit_group
     *
     * @orm:Column(name="commit_group", type="string", length=32, nullable=true)
     */
    private $commit_group;

    /**
     * @var string $commit_key
     *
     * @orm:Column(name="commit_key", type="string", length=13, nullable=true)
     */
    private $commit_key;

    /**
     * @var string $record_checksum
     *
     * @orm:Column(name="record_checksum", type="string", length=32, nullable=true)
     */
    private $record_checksum;
```

The rest of the class is getter/setter methods, so I will leave it out. To see the entire Entity file, I put it up on pastebin ( http://pastebin.com/9LheZ6A1 ). The 'commit_key' I'd just added a few weeks ago, with no problems.

Now I update the schema:

```
$ doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql
ALTER TABLE cloud ADD record_checksum VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT NULL;
$ doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --force
Updating database schema...
Database schema updated successfully!
```

I verified this field now exists in the DB table.

However, when I run a simple DQL query like this:

```
$dql =  "SELECT c.id AS id, c.commit_key AS key, c.record_checksum AS checksum ".
                "FROM Entity\\Cloud c WHERE c.commit_group = :commit_group";
```

I get the error:

```
 [Semantical Error] line 0, col 42 near 'record_checksum': Error: Class Entity\Cloud has no field or association named record_checksum,
```

I've banged my head on the wall over this for a while now. I'm sure I'm overlooking something really stupid. Any help is greatly appreciated!
-Nick

Comment: Can you use alias in dql? For example does `select c from Entity\Cloud c` work?

Comment: When I try that, I get this error: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens,

Comment: May have to remove the bind to `:commit_group` if you removed that from the dql. Not sure if you removed the where clause or not.

Comment: ah, of course. so using, for example: SELECT c FROM Entity\Cloud c WHERE c.id = 0, returns successfully, with all the fields EXCEPT for  record_checksum

Comment: That's strange. Your mapping looks right. Are there any records with a record_checksum yet in the db? Or can you not even call getRecordCheckSum() (or whatever you called the getter)?

Comment: I was using getArrayResult(), so I could dump the contents and view the fields easily. When I use $em->find('Entity\Cloud', 0); I can call getRecordChecksum() successfully and it (correctly) returns an empty var.

Comment: Correction! when I put in some test data manually into the record_checksum field, then called $c->getRecordChecksum() it still returned nothing. No errors, but no successful retrieval of the test data.

Comment: In the hopes it may help to see my entire Entity\Cloud.php, here's the pastebin url: http://pastebin.com/9LheZ6A1

Comment: 1) clear cache if you have any 2) try to rename the field

Comment: @meze - thanks very much for your reply. Turns out the only thing I changed between now and the last time I added any doctrine entity fields, was setting up memcached! :P restarting memcached fixed the problem. If you post the answer I will mark it

Comment: @NickJennings ok transformed it into an answer ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to:

1. Clear any cache that may contain the config or PHP code.
2. Rename a field in case the first solution didn't work.

Comment: I'd completely forgotten that I recently setup memcached! restarting that fixed the problem. Thanks a lot for the idiot-checklist :)

Comment: I have configured apcu as metadata cache drive so after reloading PHP-FPM daemon, it worked  https://ma.ttias.be/clear-apc-cache-php/

Answer (score 1):

Go to the `Entity` in question and check the variable name. If it's something like `TESTVar`, and you're trying to use `testVar` in the query, it's going to give you the error that the variable doesn't exist in the `Entity`.

Change the query to use `TESTVar` instead of `testVar`, and it will work.

Comment: You saved me ! Idk how much and what have i went through so far, but this was the actual issue. Thx