# symfony2 or doctrine are removing username field from my entities -- why?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

**Update: It's not just `username` that's this affects. I even tried renaming the column to `foo` in my schema, and still it always returns `null` for that column!**

My database is in MySQL (InnoDB). I have a `users` table, containing the properties `ID`, `username`, `name`, `email`, `password`. Table has a bunch of users inserted in it.

On the Doctrine side, my `AppBundle\Entity\User` class is correctly defined. I can query my users and get a list of them, with all the columns intact -- except for the `username` column.

Despite `username` being defined in PHP:

```
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="username_UNIQUE", columns={"username"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=45,  nullable=false)
     */
    private $username;

    // ...


    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get username
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }
```

When I get the entities and dump them, the username field has mysteriously been nulled:

```
User {#389 ▼
  -id: 2
  -username: null
  -name: "Sam"
  -password: XXX
  -email: XXX
  -oPhone: ""
  -mPhone: XXX
  -hPhone: ""
  -institutions: PersistentCollection {#390 ▶}
}
```

Even though it definitely exists and is not null on the database:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=2

# ID, username, name, password, email, o_phone, m_phone, h_phone
2, sjw, Sam, XXX, XXX, , XXX,
```

And trying to access the field via PHP results in it complaining that no such `username` field exists, preventing me from doing user auth using this entity.

- I'm not using any custom app bundles in Symfony, which is version 2.7.6 (with doctrine2), on PHP 5.4.
- I've cleared my caches, made sure I haven't had any Doctrine-generated .yml or .xml models lying around.
- I've sanity-checked my database -- using the sqlalchemy Python library and `sqlacodegen` I have a python version of my ORM. That has no problems with the `username` column, results appear as they should, rather than being null or NoneType.
- I've temporarily disabled the SecurityBundle to see if it was removing the username behind the scenes -- the field is still nulled.
- I've pored over the Symfony docs...

Nope, out of ideas. What is Symfony doing behind the scenes?

Comment: change your model to `public $username;`

Comment: "And trying to access the field via PHP" are you using $user->getUsername() when you the error?

Comment: Can't recall what the error was -- when I was trying to use the class for user authentication, the framework was throwing errors about `username` not being a field (even when it was set to public). That was yesterday's work, however.. :p

Comment: add to your question how do you saving user

Comment: @Dale setting Entity fields to public is a VERY bad idea.

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo why's that?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out it was a cache problem, as the [chosen answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711211/doctrine-2-error-class-has-no-field-or-association-named) explains. I completely forgot that I had enabled APC to cache database entries! Turns out it was also caching the database metadata and various bits of code, so even when I was clearing everything else out, the APC cache didn't get updated.

This was the culprit, these lines in `config.yml` which should **only** have been in `config_prod.yml`:

```
    doctrine:
        orm:
            metadata_cache_driver: apc
            result_cache_driver: apc
            query_cache_driver: apc
```

(Another solution might have been to just restart `php-fpm`, as that's how I'm running PHP in my environment -- something that would have taken a second to do but I didn't think of for a whole two days... doh...)